# Gazebo Garden applying force to model via AddWorldForce fuction not acting as expected

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin

My goal is to apply a force to a gazebo model when prompted via a topic.

To do this I'm reading the force and then applying it to the link of that model via the `AddWorldForce` command in the `PreUpdate` step. I assume that calling `AddWorldForce` applies an acceleration to the link on that timestep, however, when I run this the object does not move.

Am I misunderstanding the function? I assumed that the `AddWorldForce` function should work similarly to the `SetLinearVelocity`. However, I have tested my code by replacing the `AddWorldForce` function with `SetLinearVelocity` and it acts as I would expect.

Below I've added my full `PreUpdate` function, any insights into what I'm misunderstanding would be great.

````cpp
void ForceManager::PreUpdate(const gz::sim::UpdateInfo &_info, 
gz::sim::EntityComponentManager &_ecm) {
    if(_info.paused){return;}
    if(topic_msg){
        

        auto model_entities = entitiesFromScopedName(_model_name,_ecm);

        
        for(auto model_entity : model_entities){

            gz::sim::Model model(model_entity);
            
            if(!model.Valid(_ecm)){
                gzerr << "found model ["<<_model_name<<"] but model not valid\n";
            }
            

                gz::sim::Link link(model.LinkByName(_ecm,_link_name));
                if(!link.Valid(_ecm)){
                    gzmsg << "Link entity not valid\n";

                }
                else{
                    gzmsg << "link found with name["<<link.Name(_ecm).value_or("empty") <<"]\n";
                    gz::math::Vector3d forceVector(topic_msg->x(),topic_msg->y(),topic_msg->z());
                    gzmsg << "set force:\n" << forceVector << "\n";

                    link.AddWorldForce(_ecm,forceVector);


                }
   


            


        }
        i++;
        if(i>1000){ // this is just a temporary hack to get this code to run in the first 1000 simulation steps after the message has been sent 
            topic_msg = std::nullopt;
            i=0;
        }
   
        // 
    }


}
```
````

Comment: At first sight this seems ok. I do assume you are using Dart though, for TPE `AddWorldForce()` is not implemented. Maybe there's an issue with the force units or inertial properties of your model? Are you testing on a single object (i.e. not constrained by joints to other objects)? If not, I would try this first. E.g. just a small box resting on the ground plane, not too high or too low weight (e.g. 1 kg), inertial matrix correctly specified accordingly and a force in a known direction. If you want to rule out friction with the ground you could use a sphere instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AddWorldForce` needs the entity to have a `WorldPose` component for it to work. The easiest way to create that component on the link is to call `Link::EnableVelocityChecks` at least one iteration before calling `AddWorldForce`.

Note, this might not be required in future versions of Gazebo as changes in [this](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/pull/2081) PR, if merged, will make it possible to use `AddWorldForce` without calling `EnableVelocityChecks`.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly.